# ObjectMapper and Class.forName()

Tags: java, android, jackson

I'm trying to use Jackson's ObjectMapper combined with `Class.forName` method.

```
private Object createObject(String json, String rootName) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                false);
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.model." + Finder.findClassName(rootName));
        return mapper.treeToValue(root.get("rootName"), clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

It's not working and I'm getting the following error message:

> ```
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()'
> on a null object reference
> ```

However, there are no null references because `clazz` variable isn't so. What could be the error cause?

Comment: Can you print the stack trace to show where exactly exception is coming from? It is difficult to guess otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I wrote rootName as literal String, not as variable name.

```
return mapper.treeToValue(root.get("rootName"), clazz); // wrong
return mapper.treeToValue(root.get(rootName), clazz);  //  correct
```